# How to add to a cnetplot using ggplot functions?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I have a dataset in R that is a class of 'Formal class enrichResult'. I plot the genes in this dataset using `cnetplot()` from the package DOSE - which is meant to be based on ggplot graphics. This plots a network of genes in interacting pathways:
[image]

I code for this with:

```
kegg_organism = "hsa"
kegg_enrich <-  enrichKEGG(gene   = df$geneID,
                   organism     = 'hsa',
                   pvalueCutoff = 0.05,
                   pAdjustMethod = 'fdr')

kegg <- setReadable(kegg_enrich, 'org.Hs.eg.db', 'ENTREZID')
kegg_genes <- kegg[,]

gene_of_interest <- dplyr::filter(kegg_genes, grepl('CALML6', geneID))
gene_of_interest <- enrichDF2enrichResult(gene_of_interest)

gene_list_scores <- df$Score
names(gene_list_scores) <- df$geneID
gene_list_scores <- na.omit(gene_list_scores)
gene_list_scores <- sort(gene_list_scores, decreasing = TRUE)

plot <- cnetplot(gene_of_interest, foldChange = gene_list_scores)

plot <- plot + scale_color_gradient2(name='Score', low='steelblue', high='firebrick')
```

I am looking to overlay this plot with shapes indicating categories of drug types for the genes, but I'm having trouble getting this working.

I have the drug data separate to the enrichResult data, my drug data looks like:

```
drugs <- structure(list(Gene = c("ACE", "AQP1", "IRS2", "SMAD3", 
"HLA-B"), Druggability = c("KINASE", "DRUGGABLE GENOME", "CLINICALLY ACTIONABLE", 
"KINASE", "CLINICALLY ACTIONABLE")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

#drugs data is 2 columns like:
Gene        Druggability
TLN2        KINASE
PDGFC       DRUGGABLE GENOME
```

I am coding to overlay drug shapes on the plot like this:

```
drugs <- fread('genes_dgidb_export.tsv')
drugs <- dplyr::select(drugs, Gene, Druggability)
drugs <- drugs[1:80,] #making data same size otherwise I get an Aesthetics number mismatch error
Druggability <- drugs$Druggability
names(Druggability) <- drugs$Gene

options(ggrepel.max.overlaps = Inf)
pother <- cnetplot(gene_of_interest,
                   categorySize ='pvalue', 
                   foldChange = gene_list_scores, 
                  )

pother <- pother + scale_color_gradient2(name='Score', low='steelblue', high='red') +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(2, 8)) 

#Overlaying shapes by drug:
library(ggraph)

pother + geom_node_point(aes(shape=Druggability)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(2, 5, 3, 4))
```

[image]

However, the the shapes overlayed here are mismatched/in the wrong places, and there are drugs assigned to pathway nodes in beige when they should only be assigned to the red gene nodes.

Are there any other functions I could use to overlay shape points on this plot to correctly correspond with the genes?

Example input data and packages use to get the enrichResult:

```
library(data.table)
library(clusterProfiler)
library(enrichplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(DOSE)
library(clusterProfiler)
library(multienrichjam)
library(RColorBrewer)

df <- structure(list(geneID = c(107986084L, 100874369L, 100506380L, 100288797L, 
100137049L, 100130742L, 723788L, 643136L, 641649L, 497258L), 
    Score = c(0.809859097, 0.913054347, 0.423823357, 0.369738668, 
    0.798110485, 0.78013134, 0.764999211, 0.231925398, 0.317150593, 
    0.754656732)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

kegg_genes <- structure(list(ID = c("hsa04924", "hsa04925", "hsa04022", "hsa04934", 
"hsa05166", "hsa04218", "hsa05410", "hsa04024", "hsa05414", "hsa04933"
), Description = c("Renin secretion", "Aldosterone synthesis and secretion", 
"cGMP-PKG signaling pathway", "Cushing syndrome", "Human T-cell leukemia virus 1 infection", 
"Cellular senescence", "Hypertrophic cardiomyopathy", "cAMP signaling pathway", 
"Dilated cardiomyopathy", "AGE-RAGE signaling pathway in diabetic complications"
), GeneRatio = c("22/381", "25/381", "31/381", "28/381", "33/381", 
"27/381", "20/381", "32/381", "20/381", "20/381"), BgRatio = c("69/8093", 
"98/8093", "167/8093", "155/8093", "222/8093", "156/8093", "90/8093", 
"219/8093", "96/8093", "100/8093"), pvalue = c(2.67752556162864e-13, 
1.75172505637096e-12, 3.06146322777988e-11, 5.54589140412457e-10, 
2.99051127478473e-09, 3.0449722225371e-09, 4.26754375382907e-09, 
8.08219152477885e-09, 1.39375994107875e-08, 2.90351315318027e-08
), p.adjust = c(8.19322821858365e-11, 2.68013933624758e-10, 3.12269249233547e-09, 
4.2426069241553e-08, 1.55293583349392e-07, 1.55293583349392e-07, 
1.86552626953099e-07, 3.09143825822791e-07, 4.73878379966775e-07, 
8.88475024873162e-07), qvalue = c(4.70680809254719e-11, 1.53967412849448e-10, 
1.79391003171663e-09, 2.43727332760211e-08, 8.92123440638062e-08, 
8.92123440638062e-08, 1.0716989577285e-07, 1.77595524294483e-07, 
2.72231473871522e-07, 5.10407049032742e-07), geneID = c("CALML6/CALML4/PLCB1/CLCA2/PPP3CA/PLCB3/PDE3A/PDE1A/NPR1/NPPA/GNAS/EDNRA/EDN1/ACE/CACNA1D/CACNA1C/AQP1/AGT/ADRB2/ADRB1/ADORA1/ADCY5", 
"CALML6/CALML4/KCNK9/PRKD3/PLCB1/CREB5/PRKD1/PRKCE/PLCB3/NPR1/NPPA/LDLR/KCNK3/GNAS/CYP21A2/CYP11B2/CAMK2B/CACNA1D/CACNA1C/ATP2B1/ATF1/AGT/ADCY9/ADCY5/ADCY3", 
"CALML6/CALML4/PLCB1/CREB5/IRS2/PDE5A/SLC8A1/MAP2K2/PRKCE/PPP3CA/PLCB3/PDE3A/NPR1/NPPB/NPPA/NFATC2/MEF2A/INSR/GTF2I/EDNRA/CACNA1D/CACNA1C/ATP2B1/AKT2/ADRB2/ADRB1/ADRA2B/ADORA1/ADCY9/ADCY5/ADCY3", 
"WNT3A/LEF1/PDE11A/PLCB1/CREB5/TCF7L2/MAP2K2/PLCB3/PBX1/LDLR/KCNK3/GNAS/DVL1/CYP21A2/CYP17A1/CYP11B1/CDKN2C/CDKN1A/CDK6/CCNE1/CAMK2B/CACNA1D/CACNA1C/CCND1/AGT/ADCY9/ADCY5/ADCY3", 
"TLN2/VAC14/CREB5/CDC16/KAT2B/PIK3R3/MAD1L1/XPO1/TLN1/TGFB2/TGFB1/TERT/STAT5B/RELA/PTEN/MAP2K2/PPP3CA/NFKBIA/NFATC2/SMAD3/IL6/HLA-DQB1/HLA-DQA1/HLA-B/CDKN2C/CDKN1A/CDC20/CCNE1/CCND1/AKT2/ADCY9/ADCY5/ADCY3", 
"CALML6/CALML4/TRPM7/HIPK2/BTRC/PIK3R3/TGFB2/TGFB1/RRAS/RELA/PTEN/MAP2K2/PPP3CA/NFATC2/SMAD3/IL6/IGFBP3/HLA-B/FOXO3/CDKN1A/CDK6/CDC25A/CCNE1/CACNA1D/ZFP36L1/CCND1/AKT2", 
"PRKAG2/CACNA2D2/TGFB2/TGFB1/SLC8A1/SGCD/PRKAG1/ITGB5/ITGA9/ITGA1/IL6/IGF1/EDN1/ACE/DAG1/CACNB4/CACNB2/CACNA1D/CACNA1C/AGT", 
"CALML6/CALML4/PDE10A/CREB5/PIK3R3/RRAS/RELA/MAP2K2/PDE3A/NPR1/NPPA/NFKBIA/HTR1D/GRIN2B/GNAS/GIPR/GIP/EDNRA/EDN1/CHRM2/CAMK2B/CACNA1D/CACNA1C/ATP2B1/AKT2/ADRB2/ADRB1/ADORA1/ADCY9/ADCY5/ADCY3/ACOX1", 
"CACNA2D2/TGFB2/TGFB1/SLC8A1/SGCD/ITGB5/ITGA9/ITGA1/IGF1/GNAS/DAG1/CACNB4/CACNB2/CACNA1D/CACNA1C/AGT/ADRB1/ADCY9/ADCY5/ADCY3", 
"PLCD3/NOX4/PLCB1/PIK3R3/VEGFA/TGFB2/TGFB1/STAT5B/RELA/PRKCE/PLCB3/SMAD3/IL6/FN1/EDN1/COL4A4/BCL2/CCND1/AKT2/AGT"
), Count = c(22L, 25L, 31L, 28L, 33L, 27L, 20L, 32L, 20L, 20L
)), row.names = c("hsa04924", "hsa04925", "hsa04022", "hsa04934", 
"hsa05166", "hsa04218", "hsa05410", "hsa04024", "hsa05414", "hsa04933"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Output plot from running with example data above (previous plots are with my whole data):

[image]

I've underlined in red using paint the genes that have a druggability assigned to them, but for some reason the shapes are going to the pathway nodes.

Comment: Can't reproduce, `gene_of_interest` is empty.

Comment: But I am guessing issue is on this line: `geom_node_point`, try to subset the data before plotting to include only genes that are present in `Druggability`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it must not have been a big enough sample to run through the kegg enrichment. I've tried providing the ```kegg_genes``` as a sample instead which should run through to the plot now (just with different pathways output but same principle). The code should now all run with results, the only thing is that in df I only give 10 sample genes and their ```Scores``` so the plot points will not be colored in red, but I know that step works for me, so I've just made sure the genes in my ```Druggability```data are genes that should give shapes on the example plot.

Comment: I will look into making a ```cnetplot()``` now with the gene subset of those only present in ```Druggability``` too, thank you for this suggestion

Comment: Although also the gene list in ```Druggability``` for my real data is made from only genes that enter the cnetplot (with genes that didn't have a ```Druggability``` getting assigned just 'NA' in that ```Druggability``` column, but there are not any extra genes that don't appear in the plot.

Comment: If you have a "complicated" plot like this that you want to create, I would try to recreate it using the "base" tools, eg in your case ggplot as well as ggraph. You could set the value of your different pathway groups to NA to differentiate them from your gene nodes and then follow your old ideas

Comment: Looking at the [source code for the cnetplot function](https://rdrr.io/bioc/enrichplot/src/R/cnetplot.R) it looks complicated but possible to alter the function to get the effect you're after. Perhaps try reaching out to the author: Guangchuang Yu (guangchuangyu@gmail.com / https://twitter.com/guangchuangyu)

Comment: Hi @DN1 for the Druggability data you had used the categories.tsv from  https://www.dgidb.org/downloads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I used the clusterProfiler example to make the code reproducible (https://yulab-smu.top/biomedical-knowledge-mining-book/universal-api.html)
2. I used the categories.tsv file from (https://www.dgidb.org/downloads)

```
library(clusterProfiler)
library(dplyr)
library(ggraph)
library(msigdbr)

data(geneList, package="DOSE")
cat_table = read.table("categories.tsv",sep="\t",header = T,quote = "" )
geneList=geneList[c(1:50,12476:12495)] # a 70 gene sub list to simplify the plot
m_t2g <- msigdbr(species = "Homo sapiens", category = "H") %>% 
  dplyr::select(gs_name, entrez_gene) 
em2 <- GSEA(geneList, TERM2GENE = m_t2g)
em2 = setReadable(em2, 'org.Hs.eg.db', 'ENTREZID')
p = cnetplot(em2,foldChange = geneList)
m = match(p$data$name ,cat_table$entrez_gene_symbol)
category = cat_table$category[m]
p + geom_node_point(aes(shape= category))
```

[image]

The point here is to match the gene name with the names in the cnetplot object (p$data$name) that contains the gene names and pathway names so the matching is essential

to make a verif

```
cat_table[m[!is.na(m)],c(1,4)]
```

```
       entrez_gene_symbol              category
6211               KIF23                ENZYME
13765              CENPE                KINASE
```